# Simple temperature monitor Raspberry Pi 2 + GPIOs with DS18B20 on WIndows 10 Universal App

Tags: ds18b20, windows-iot

Can somebody give me simple example code for Microsoft Windows 10 Core for IoT - Windows Universal App project C# , for having Raspberry Pi 2 with Windows 10 and reading temperature from GPIO with DS18B20 sensor ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Highly unlikely.

The DS18B20 requires being able to do timings of the order of microseconds.

Currently Windows IoT on the Pi seems to have a delay granularity of a millisecond.

Comment: Ok, thank you for info, is there any official documentation about this limitation or specification attribute ?

Comment: I have not seen any, but I have not looked.  I am basing my opinion on posts like [this](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=763146#p763146).

Comment: Now that RTM version is out, is it sill limitation ?

Comment: https://microsoft.hackster.io/en-US/windowsiot/build-hands-on-lab-iot-weather-station-using-windows-10

Answer (score 3):

[Sample project](https://www.hackster.io/selom/1-wire-ds18b20-sensor-on-windows-10-iot-core-raspberry-pi-2-7d9b67) is available here: https://github.com/selomkofori/ds18b20_win10iot

The DS18B20 is a digital temperature sensor that uses a 1-wire interface which only requires 1 port pin for communication.

Unlike other platforms, Windows 10 IoT does not have libraries or micro-second timer resolution needed to read 1-wire devices.

This project uses the UART0 Rx/Tx pins to communicate and read temperature values from the DS18B20, and can probably be easily adapted to read other 1-wire devices.

The code is based on Electric Imp's 1-wire bus over UART found here:
https://electricimp.com/docs/resources/onewire/

A second alternative is to acquire a [DS2428-100 Single-channel 1-Wire Master](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/products/interface/controllers-expanders/DS2482-100.html) chip that can interface between I2C and 1-Wire devices. The following code can be used for that: https://github.com/Rinsen/OneWire

A third alternative is to use an Arduino device in "slave mode", and accessed via the I2C bus. See: http://blog.oscarliang.net/raspberry-pi-arduino-connected-i2c/

Answer (score 1):

[BMP180 Sensor](https://www.hackster.io/acegrc/bmp180-windows-iot-d14b76) project will do temperature for you.  The sensors are only $7.00 on Amazon.  Use the link above and it will guide you all the way through the process.  Just not the same chip.